# GSAP - Javascript: The specifier “gsap/dist/gsap” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything

Tags: javascript, flask, ecmascript-6, gsap, umd

I am trying to use the JavaScript GSAP library in a web project (running on Python Flask framework). I have this `animate.js` script, with the following content:

```
import { gsap } from "gsap/dist/gsap";
    
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/dist/ScrollTrigger";
import { MotionPathPlugin } from "gsap/dist/MotionPathPlugin";
import { TextPlugin } from "gsap/dist/TextPlugin";


gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger,MotionPathPlugin,TextPlugin);
```

I generated the above from the GSAP [installation docs](https://gsap.com/docs/v3/Installation) as a UMD (universal module definition) import. However, when I attempt to run the script (on Firefox), I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “gsap/dist/gsap” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.`

I have tried switching between UMD and ESM imports, but I still get the same error message. I need help understanding the exception message and how I can resolve the error.

Comment: Take try to `import gsap from 'gsap';` and then `import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/dist/ScrollTrigger";`
`import { MotionPathPlugin } from "gsap/dist/MotionPathPlugin";`
`import { TextPlugin } from "gsap/dist/TextPlugin";`